# How to disable IDFA useage in admob

Tags: ios, admob, idfa

I am using AdMob in my app. I want to know how to disable IDFA in the admob SDK. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I’ve submitted an app targeted for kids category, integrated AdMob and it’s rejected because of IDFA usage, any workaround would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the Google Mobile Ads SDK is to serve personalized ads. If a user has consented to receive only non-personalized ads, you can configure an AdRequest object with the following code to specify that only non-personalized ads should be requested:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.AddExtra("npa", "1")
.Build();
```

It's for Unity, but you can find solution for your platform.

https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/eu-consent